# Match Date from a string and convert UTC to Local

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have following message on Login Failed response. The response shows Date in UTC format. I wanted to get the date and convert from UTC to Local.
I tried the following but I'm still having the same date formate. Can anyone help me what I'm doing wrong here

```
var loginRes = 'Too many incorrect attempts. Account is locked until: 2018-03-16T05:13:58+00:00'


var dateRegx = /\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}-\d{2}:\d{2}/;
var ErrorMessage = (loginRes).replace(dateRegx, 
  function(match){
       return moment(match).format("MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a");
});
console.log(ErrorMessage);
```

On my console print, I'm having same as LoginRes. I was expecting something like :

`Too many incorrect attempts. Account is locked until: March 16th 2018, 8:13:14 pm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also solve this using [`lastIndexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf):

```js
var loginRes = 'Too many incorrect attempts. Account is locked until: 2018-03-16T05:13:58+00:00';
var idx = loginRes.lastIndexOf(' ');
var ErrorMessage = loginRes.substring(0, idx) + ' ' +
  moment(loginRes.substring(idx)).format("MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a");

console.log(ErrorMessage);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.21.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. This is something  interesting

Answer (score 1):

Your regex doesn't match the date

```
var loginRes = 'Too many incorrect attempts. Account is locked until: 2018-03-16T05:13:58+00:00'


    var dateRegx = /(\d{4}-[01]\d-[0-3]\dT[0-2]\d:[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d\.\d+([+-][0-2]\d:[0-5]\d|Z))|(\d{4}-[01]\d-[0-3]\dT[0-2]\d:[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d([+-][0-2]\d:[0-5]\d|Z))|(\d{4}-[01]\d-[0-3]\dT[0-2]\d:[0-5]\d([+-][0-2]\d:[0-5]\d|Z))/;
    var ErrorMessage = (loginRes).replace(dateRegx, 
      function(match){
      console.log('tst')
           return moment(match).format("MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a");
    });
    console.log(ErrorMessage);
```

Comment: You are right, regex was wrong. Then I have to use momentjs to convert  UTC to Local?

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is incorrect, it does not match the `+` before offset, you can use `/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\+\d{2}:\d{2}/` instead.

Moreover you can use [`moment.utc`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) to parse your input as UTC and [`local()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/local/) to convert it in local mode.

```js
var loginRes = 'Too many incorrect attempts. Account is locked until: 2018-03-16T05:13:58+00:00'

var dateRegx = /\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\+\d{2}:\d{2}/;
var ErrorMessage = (loginRes).replace(dateRegx, 
  function(match){
       return moment.utc(match).local().format("MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a");
});
console.log(ErrorMessage);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```